# AttributeError: module 'miceforest' has no attribute 'MultipleImputedKernel' error

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn

Installed miceForest with `!pip install miceforest` and no issue with installation

```
Collecting miceforest
  Downloading miceforest-5.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (69 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from miceforest) (1.20.1)
Collecting lightgbm>=3.3.1
  Downloading lightgbm-3.3.1-py3-none-win_amd64.whl (1.0 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: wheel in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from lightgbm>=3.3.1->miceforest) (0.36.2)
Requirement already satisfied: scikit-learn!=0.22.0 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from lightgbm>=3.3.1->miceforest) (0.24.1)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from lightgbm>=3.3.1->miceforest) (1.6.2)
Requirement already satisfied: joblib>=0.11 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from scikit-learn!=0.22.0->lightgbm>=3.3.1->miceforest) (1.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: threadpoolctl>=2.0.0 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from scikit-learn!=0.22.0->lightgbm>=3.3.1->miceforest) (2.1.0)
Installing collected packages: lightgbm, miceforest
Successfully installed lightgbm-3.3.1 miceforest-5.2.0
```

No issue with below code

```
import miceforest as mf
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
```

But getting error while referring to `MultipleImputedKernel`

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-b346f2744b14> in <module>
----> 1 kernel = mf.MultipleImputedKernel(
      2   iris_amp,
      3   datasets=4,
      4   save_all_iterations=True,
      5   random_state=1991

AttributeError: module 'miceforest' has no attribute 'MultipleImputedKernel'
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Any help to fix the issue will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

New main classes (`ImputationKernel`, `ImputedData`) have replaced (`KernelDataSet`, `MultipleImputedKernel`, `ImputedDataSet`, `MultipleImputedDataSet`).

Comment: This answer would be improved with an [edit] to add a link to the reference material that explains this change.